# jQuery - Select empty input with class name

Tags: jquery

How to select empty all 'input type="text"' elements with class name 'myTextbox"

example below only selects empty fields

var emptyfields = $("input[value=]");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(":text.myTextBox[value='']")...
```